# Can I assign a reset index a name?

Tags: python, pandas

Normally when a dataframe undergoes a `reset_index()` the new column is assigned the name `index` or `level_i` depending on the level.

Is it possible to assign the new column a name?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You can call `rename` on the returned df from `reset_index`:

```
In [145]:
# create a df
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3))
df

Out[145]:
          0         1         2
0 -2.845811 -0.182439 -0.526785
1 -0.112547  0.661461  0.558452
2  0.587060 -1.232262 -0.997973
3 -1.009378 -0.062442  0.125875
4 -1.129376  3.282447 -0.403731
```

Set the index name

```
In [146]:    
df.index = df.index.set_names(['foo'])
df

Out[146]:
            0         1         2
foo                              
0   -2.845811 -0.182439 -0.526785
1   -0.112547  0.661461  0.558452
2    0.587060 -1.232262 -0.997973
3   -1.009378 -0.062442  0.125875
4   -1.129376  3.282447 -0.403731
```

call `reset_index` and chain with `rename`:

```
In [147]:
df.reset_index().rename(columns={df.index.name:'bar'})

Out[147]:
   bar         0         1         2
0    0 -2.845811 -0.182439 -0.526785
1    1 -0.112547  0.661461  0.558452
2    2  0.587060 -1.232262 -0.997973
3    3 -1.009378 -0.062442  0.125875
4    4 -1.129376  3.282447 -0.403731
```

Thanks to @ayhan

alternatively you can use `rename_axis` to rename the index prior to `reset_index`:

```
In [149]:
df.rename_axis('bar').reset_index()

Out[149]:
   bar         0         1         2
0    0 -2.845811 -0.182439 -0.526785
1    1 -0.112547  0.661461  0.558452
2    2  0.587060 -1.232262 -0.997973
3    3 -1.009378 -0.062442  0.125875
4    4 -1.129376  3.282447 -0.403731
```

or just overwrite the index name directly first:

```
df.index.name = 'bar'
```

and then call `reset_index`

Comment: The part after "alternatively you can" works for me, the method before it does not seem to (it doesn't rename the old column, keeps it as "index").

Comment: @Edchum apparently this hasnt been working in my case, perhaps because when you reset_index , the old column is automatically named index. Now using df.index would point to the new index created, and df['index'] would refer to the old column. Using df.index.name would try and rename the new column instead of the old column naming "index". I scratched my head around this problem for quite some time when using this method didnt produce the same results as they did for your case, resolved the issue by using igorkf's solution

Comment: If using a single level, `df.rename_axis('bar').reset_index()` is the most direct and readable approach to me.

Answer (score 42):

You could do this (Jan of 2020):

```
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'bar'})
print(df)
   bar         0         1         2
0    0 -2.845811 -0.182439 -0.526785
1    1 -0.112547  0.661461  0.558452
2    2  0.587060 -1.232262 -0.997973
3    3 -1.009378 -0.062442  0.125875
4    4 -1.129376  3.282447 -0.403731
```

Answer (score 41):

For a **Series** you can specify the name directly. E.g.:

```
>>> df.groupby('s1').size().reset_index(name='new_name')
  s1  new_name
0  b         1
1  r         1
2  s         1
```

Answer (score 9):

You can try the `names` parameter introduced in **version 1.5.0**, from [`DataFrame.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

> **names**: *int, str or 1-dimensional list, default None*
>
> Using the given string, rename the DataFrame column which contains the index data. If the DataFrame has a MultiIndex, this has to be a list or tuple with length equal to the number of levels.

For a single index level dataframe:

```
         class  max_speed                                        name   class  max_speed
falcon    bird      389.0   df.reset_index(names='name')    0  falcon    bird      389.0
parrot    bird       24.0  ------------------------------>  1  parrot    bird       24.0
lion    mammal       80.5                                   2    lion  mammal       80.5
monkey  mammal        NaN                                   3  monkey  mammal        NaN
```

For a multiple index level dataframe:

```
               speed species                                                   classes   names  speed species
                 max    type                                                                      max    type
class  name                                                                  0    bird  falcon  389.0     fly
bird   falcon  389.0     fly   df.reset_index(names=['classes', 'names'])    1    bird  parrot   24.0     fly
       parrot   24.0     fly  -------------------------------------------->  2  mammal    lion   80.5     run
mammal lion     80.5     run                                                 3  mammal  monkey    NaN    jump
       monkey    NaN    jump
```

If you only care about one level in Multiindex

```
               speed species                                                            classes  speed species
                 max    type                                                                       max    type
class  name                    df.reset_index(level='class', names='classes')    name
bird   falcon  389.0     fly  ------------------------------------------------>  falcon    bird  389.0     fly
       parrot   24.0     fly                                                     parrot    bird   24.0     fly
mammal lion     80.5     run                                                     lion    mammal   80.5     run
       monkey    NaN    jump                                                     monkey  mammal    NaN    jump
```

NOTE: `reset_index()` is not inplaced by default, you need assign the result back or use `inplace=True`, for example

```py
df = df.reset_index(names='name')
# or
df.reset_index(names='name', inplace=True)
```

Comment: This (simply using the `names` argument to `reset_index()`) is much better than the accepted and most highly rated solution! 
`df.reset_index(names='name')`

Comment: @JoAnnAlvarez I think it's because the names argument didn't exist at the time that the other solutions were given. I agree this is the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you are seeking one-liners that return a new DataFrame, use [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html). Here's an example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [4.4, 2.2], "b": 8}, index=[10, 20])
>>> df
      a  b
10  4.4  8
20  2.2  8
```

Assign a `bar` Series with the index values, but keep the original index:

```
>>> df.assign(bar=df.index)
      a  b  bar
10  4.4  8   10
20  2.2  8   20
```

Similar, but drop the index:

```
>>> df.assign(bar=df.index).reset_index(drop=True)
     a  b  bar
0  4.4  8   10
1  2.2  8   20
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using reset_index() to go from a Series to a DataFrame you can name the column like this

```
my_series.rename('Example').reset_index()
```