# Reseting multi-inex : How to choose column-names?

Tags: python, pandas

After grouping my data with:

> d=d.groupby([d.index.year,d.index.month]).sum()

I want to reset the multi-index resulting in 2 new columns year and month.
I tried :

> d=d.reset_index(name=['year','month'])

but that throws an error : TypeError: reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'.

Using:

```
d=d.reset_index()
```

creates the two columns with names index_0 and index_1.

I could rename them but is there a better solution ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I assign a reset index a name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914200/can-i-assign-a-reset-index-a-name)

Comment: The way `reset_index()` should work is that the new columns retain the name of the corresponding index levels.